# Amazon redshift: load Avro files compressed using BZIP2

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have Avro files (compressed using BZIP2) stored in HDFS and S3 and I want to load them into Amazon Redshift. The copy command gives an error:

```
 error:  Invalid AVRO file
 code:      8001
 context:   Cannot init avro reader from s3 file File header contains an unknown codec
```

Does Redshift not support compressed Avro files?

If that's the case, what is the next best option to load this data into Redshift (without converting them back into Avro files without compression).

Can I use sqoop?

Comment: Did you specify `format as avro` in your COPY command. Can you share your copy command syntax sample

Answer (score 0):

Redshift does support compressed avro files.

To load the data files that are compressed using gzip, lzop, or bzip2, include the corresponding option: GZIP, LZOP, or BZIP2 in the copy command.

Also, you need to mention avro format and provide the json path. Below is the code that i have used and it works.

```
    copy <tablename> from '<s3 path - abc.avro.gz>'
    credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<access-key>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret access key>'
    format as avro '<json path for avro format>'
    gzip;
```

Comment: You don't need to specify a JSON path if you're just using the file's built-in schema - can just do "format as avro 'auto'", see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#copy-from-avro-examples-using-auto

Answer (score 0):

A little late to this party.

Redshift only accepts compressed Avro which has been compressed with deflate or Snappy.

From the docs:

> Avro is a data serialization protocol. An Avro source file includes a
> schema that defines the structure of the data. The Avro schema type
> must be record. COPY accepts Avro files created using the default
> uncompressed codec as well as the deflate and snappy compression
> codecs. For more information about Avro, go to Apache Avro.

[Redshift docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html#copy-avro)

The original problem has likely been solved, but this may help someone in the future.